# How I can make the launcher of BURAI for Quantum espresso in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, launcher, directory, chmod

I am trying to install BURAI for Quantum espresso on Ubuntu. I am new on Ubuntu, and I keep getting the message below every time I try to make the BURAI launcher file using "makeLauncher.sh" of BURAI package.

> /media/arnab/New Volume2/Essentials/Quantum Espresso/LINUX/BURAI/BURAI1.3.2/makeLauncher.sh: 18: /media/arnab/New Volume2/Essentials/Quantum Espresso/LINUX/BURAI/BURAI1.3.2/makeLauncher.sh: cannot create BURAI.Desktop: Permission denied 
>   chmod: cannot access 'BURAI.Desktop': No such file or directory

Can someone help me with some suggestions how to solve this problem? or is there any alternative way to create this launcher?

Answer (score 0):

BURAI1.3.2/makeLauncher.sh

try using the above command in the root folder containing the "BURAI1.3.2" folder, which is the extracted file you get after unzipping the file.